# NoMethodError in Welcome#index Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo un blog en *Ruby on Rails* y tengo este error:

> NoMethodError in Welcome#index
>
> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
>
> ```
> <% @articles.each do |article| %>
>   <h1><%= article.title %></h1>
>   <div>
>     <%= article.body %>
>   </div>
> <% end %>
> ```

Ya intenté de todo y según yo no estoy cometiendo ningún error.

Este es mi controlador:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

Este es mi routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar tu controlador?

Comment: `class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @articles = Article.all
 end 
end`

Comment: Parece que es el controlador equivocado, ¿puedes compartir el código de `routes.rb`? Pero edita la pregunta y agrégalo ahí en lugar de ponerlo en un comentario.

Comment: Listo ya lo puse el routes.rb

Answer (score 4):

El problema se debe a que quieres utilizar la variable `@articles` en la vista `app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`, sin embargo esta no está definida en la acción `index` del controlador `Welcome`.

Para arreglar el problema tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambia la raíz de tu aplicación a `articles#index`:

   ```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     resources :articles
     root 'articles#index'
   end
   ```

   Si tomas esta opción verifica que tengas la vista `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`.
2. Agrega la variable `@articles` en `welcome#index`:

   ```
   def WelcomeController < ApplicationController
     def index
       @articles = Article.all
     end
   end
   ```